# In C using Xcode, how to change the while loop to mach the first for loop?

Tags: c

In C using Xcode, how to change the while loop to mach the first for loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ( i++ < 4)
        printf ("while: i%d\n",i);

    printf ("after while  loop, i=%d\n\n", i );

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf ("first for: i=%d\n", i );

    printf ("after first loop, i=%d\n\n", i );

    for ( i= 1; i <=4; i++)
        printf ("second for: i=%d\n", i );

    printf ("after second loop, i=%d\n", i );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change `while` loop to `for` loop:

```
for (i = 1; i < 5; ++i)
    printf ("while: i%d\n",i);
```

To make `while` loop print numbers like the `for` loop:

```
while ( i < 4 )
    printf ("while: i%d\n", i++);
```

Or alternatively:

```
while ( i < 4 )
{
    printf ("while: i%d\n", i);
    ++i;
}
```

Read about pre-increment vs post-increment to get the idea. For example, [here](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=171881).

Answer (score 1):

```
while ( i < 4)
        printf ("while: i=%d\n",i++);
```

will do the trick. The `++` after the `i` is a post increment, so the `printf` statement prints `i`, then increments.

Answer (score 0):

The issue there is that the `while` checks for i=0, i=1, u=2, i=3 and i=4. When it fails, it breaks, but before it breaks, it updates i once more, and sets i to i++ (i=5)

So you get

```
while: i0
while: i1
while: i2
while: i3
while: i4

after while  loop, i=5
```

But the `for` clause doesn't update i after the comparison fails, so you get

```
first for: i=0
first for: i=1
first for: i=2
first for: i=3

after first loop, i=4
```

If you want to match both clauses, try incrementing i inside the `while`, not in the condition itself.

Comment: thank you sire but when I add the incrementing  in side the while it give me this:                                                       while: i=1
while: i=2
while: i=3
while: i=4
after while  loop, i=5 but the good solution is to put incrementing  like this                                                                     while ( i < 4)
        printf ("while: i=%d\n",i++);

Comment: What I was saying is incrementing inside the while, but not before the printf, after it. Saying `printf("%d",i++);`is the same as saying `printf("%d",i); i++;` in two steps. If you do it the other way around, you get the same issue.